# root_path_page is blank until I refresh it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I know my routes are not at issue, and it's probably some js wanting to load but I don't know how to find that js. When I re-route to the home page, and look at the log and then refresh the page, both log entries are exactly the same, (200). Formerly the first iteration would show only an rss feed, but I got rid of that and now it's just blank until I hit the refresh. Happens the same on Opera, Firefox and Chrome.

What's the recommended way to troubleshoot this? Should I remove the scripts one at a time until it works right, or is there a faster way to detect exactly what script is holding things up?

Comment: Can you go into developer tools on whatever browser you're using (most of them have that stock these days) and look on the timeline to see which resources load when?

Comment: Yep. Found it watching the loading as you suggested. It was looking for an iframe. Put it in an iframe and all's well now. Thanks